# Replace append with concat

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want replace the append() with the concat() from pandas. But when i try to replace my output is different. Thank you

old with append():

```
def gettrigger(self):
    dfx = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(self.lags +1):
        mask = (self.df["%K"].shift(i) < 20) & (self.df["%D"].shift(i) < 20)
        dfx = dfx.append(mask, ignore_index=True)
    return dfx.sum(axis=0)
```

[output with append()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuFEW.png)

new with pd.concat():

```
def gettrigger(self):
    dfx = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(self.lags +1):
        mask = (self.df["%K"].shift(i) < 20) & (self.df["%D"].shift(i) < 20)
        #dfx = dfx.append(mask, ignore_index=True)
        dfx = pd.concat([dfx, mask], ignore_index=True)
    return dfx.sum(axis=0)
```

[output with pd.concat()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBpgJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

While the append method is appending data as rows to your DataFrame, the concat method is appending data as columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4))
df
    0           1           2           3
0   0.403637    -0.204563   -2.070799   0.759681
1   -0.684890   -0.651969   1.028248    0.129635
2   -1.011895   1.877984    -0.724938   0.869389
3   -1.344031   0.106898    1.762096    0.088816
4   -0.382107   1.822279    0.435752    -2.573199
5   -1.173345   -1.224242   0.887549    -0.816519
6   -1.269713   0.201384    1.576388    -1.355996
7   -0.459533   0.961355    -0.280733   -0.026496
8   0.522513    0.266246    1.066807    -0.232884
9   -0.688417   0.181908    0.356574    -0.245040
```

---

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[1]):  # Iterating through columns
    df_new = df.loc[:, i]  # loc column
    dfx = dfx.append(df_new)  # append column as new row

dfx

    0           1           2           3           4           5            6          7           8           9
0   0.403637    -0.684890   -1.011895   -1.344031   -0.382107   -1.173345   -1.269713   -0.459533   0.522513    -0.688417
1   -0.204563   -0.651969   1.877984    0.106898    1.822279    -1.224242   0.201384    0.961355    0.266246    0.181908
2   -2.070799   1.028248    -0.724938   1.762096    0.435752    0.887549    1.576388    -0.280733   1.066807    0.356574
3   0.759681    0.129635    0.869389    0.088816    -2.573199   -0.816519   -1.355996   -0.026496   -0.232884   -0.245040
```

---

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):  # Iterating through rows
    df_new = df.loc[i, :]  # loc row
    dfx = pd.concat([dfx, df_new], axis=1)  # append row as column (axis=1)

dfx

0               1           2           3           4           5            6          7           8           9
0   0.403637    -0.684890   -1.011895   -1.344031   -0.382107   -1.173345   -1.269713   -0.459533   0.522513    -0.688417
1   -0.204563   -0.651969   1.877984    0.106898    1.822279    -1.224242   0.201384    0.961355    0.266246    0.181908
2   -2.070799   1.028248    -0.724938   1.762096    0.435752    0.887549    1.576388    -0.280733   1.066807    0.356574
3   0.759681    0.129635    0.869389    0.088816    -2.573199   -0.816519   -1.355996   -0.026496   -0.232884   -0.245040
```